How to check which object type was passed in input parameter
I have a converter interface which accepts object as parameter, objects are ClaimRecord and CustomerClaim:
List<ClaimsTOObject> convert(final Object claimObject);

How do I check which object class was passed as input parameter to handle bussiness logic, as I know using instanceof is an anti-pattern

You don't. You use polymorphism. I.e., it's claimObject that has different behavior depending on its own type, not the convert method.

Oh, wait, I just noticed. The fact that you're passing Object may be an antipattern itself. What does convert do and what types of objects do you expect it to handle? Any (including, for example, List, Integer, String...) or just a specific subset of objects you defined? In that case maybe you should use an interface and then use polymorphism.

Its is converting object to transition ClaimsTOObject object, after converting I receive List as output and proceed with business logic depending on the fields that were filled in.

I updated my comment above with some more ideas.

It will handle only my specific two objects, you mean to use converter as base class which fill common fields and then create two separate classes which are extending converter and go through business logic?

No, I mean the two classes both implement an interface (for example Convertible) that defines a method convert that returns a List<ClaimsTOObject> which the convert method you defined in your question will call. So in the end you'll have List<ClaimsToObject> convert(final Convertible claimObject) { return claimObject.convert(); } or something like that. It's a bit hard to give a definite answer without a bit more context about why converter itself is an interface, for example. But that's the gist of it.

This us my converter code if it will help you:
@Override
public List convert(final Object claimObject) {
final ClaimRecord claimRecord = (ClaimRecord) claimObject;
final ClaimsTOObject claimsTOObject = new ClaimsTOObject();
final Date timestamp = new Date();
claimsTOObject.setArticleId(claimRecord.getArticleId());
claimsTOObject.setClientId(claimRecord.getClientId());

One option is to use delegation. Let's assume that convert is part of an interface named Converter. There must be an implementation for every supported type of claim, which deals only with converting this exact type.
public class ClaimRecordConverter implements Converter {

  @Override
  public List<ClaimsTOObject> convert(Object claimObject) {
    ClaimRecord claimRecord = (ClaimRecord) claimObject;
    //specific logic
    return List.of();
  }
}

Make similar implementation for CustomerClaimConverter.
And an implementation, whose responsibility is to delegate to the correct converter based on the type of claimObject.
public class DelegatingClaimConverter implements Converter {

  private final Map<Class<?>, Converter> converters = Map.of(
          CustomerClaim.class, new CustomerClaimConverter(),
          ClaimRecord.class, new ClaimRecordConverter()
  );
  //or other appropriate registration, depending on exact scenario

  @Override
  public List<ClaimsTOObject> convert(Object claimObject) {
    Class<?> claimClass = claimObject.getClass();
    Converter delegate = converters.get(claimClass);
    if (delegate == null) {
      //or another exception
      //or other appropriate handling, for example default converter
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("No converter registered for " + claimClass);
    }
    return delegate.convert(claimObject);
  }
}

Since you have tagged with spring, you can take a look at the source code of DelegatingPasswordEncoder for inspiration, it uses the same pattern.
Another option is to use a mapping library - ModelMapper, MapStruct, and many more.

You could use method-overloading.
Given the method:
List<ClaimsTOObject> convert(final Object claimObject);

You could create overloaded methods for ClaimRecord and CustomerClaim. For example;
List<ClaimsTOObject> convert(final ClaimRecord claimRecord);

List<ClaimsTOObject> convert(final CustomerClaim customerClaim);

Then, if you were to invoke the convert-method with a ClaimRecord, it will pick the second method. Meanwhile, if you were to invoke it with a String, it would use the first method (since String is an Object).
This allow you to have different ways to convert - based on the type of object - without the use of instanceOf.
